# 404 causing urllib request to freeze in try catch block

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-404, urllib

I am iterating through multiple pages with the same url except for the number at the end. Once it reaches a 404, however, it freezes the program, even though I am catching the exception in a try block. Am I missing something here? Here is my code. The program hangs once it hits https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/14587

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import urllib

ID = 14580

while ID < 132734:

    #ID == 14391
    ID == 14580
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
    reg_url = "https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/" + str(ID)
    req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 

    try:
        source = urlopen(req).read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # check the return code
                continue    
            raise
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    print(ID)
    print(reg_url)
    print(soup.title.string)
    ID += 1
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import urllib


ID = 14580

while ID < 132734:

    #ID == 14391
    ID == 14580
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
    reg_url = "https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/" + str(ID)
    req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 



    try:
        source = urlopen(req).read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # check the return code
                ID +=1
                continue    
            raise
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    print(ID)
    print(reg_url)
    print(soup.title.string)
    ID += 1
```

Comment: the `continue` prevents the `ID += 1` from being executed, so your ID is stuck at the 14587.

Comment: @JoachimLusiardi ah I missed that thanks. Any idea on a good way to keep incrementing the ID while keeping the try catch block?

Comment: I added another increment to ID inside the exception block and it works fine now

Comment: ok :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I added another increment to ID inside the exception block as seen in the updated code and it works fine now